# How to create/get a Feature class from a .lyrx file without using CreateLayer function?

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-layer, arcgis-pro-sdk

This is regarding migrating ArcMap AddIn to ArcGIS Pro. In ArcGIS Pro, depending upon the type of file (.lyrx, .shp, Raster) I need to call the corresponding ArcGIS Pro SDK API to return a feature class. With `.shp` I can create a FeatureClass but with `.lyrx` I could only find `CreateLayer` function that returns a Layer from which I can get a Feature Class.

Problem with this approach is the Layer is created directly in the Map. But I need to Join a Database table and then create the Layer. Is there a way to get the feature class form the `.lyrx` file and later create a Layer in the Map using the modified Feature Class? As I need to Join a table to the Layer and then add it to the Map.

```c#
featurelayerNew = await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
{
 var lcp = new FeatureLayerCreationParams(featureClass);
 var featureLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<FeatureLayer>(lcp, ActiveMap);
 return featureLayer;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's taken me almost 2 days to work out this code, so here it is. It's attached to a button and two key points are that it must run within a QueuedTask and that the onClick Sub needs Async added to its declaration.

```vb
 Protected Overrides Async Sub OnClick()
     ' Code assumes layerfile is referencing a geodatabase featureclass.

     Dim b As Boolean
     b = Await QueuedTask.Run(Function()
                                  ' Connect to layer file
                                  Dim sLayerFilePath As String
                                  sLayerFilePath = "c:\scratch\ORN2.lyrx"
                                  Dim lyrDoc As LayerDocument
                                  lyrDoc = New LayerDocument(sLayerFilePath)

                                  ' Create a CIM layer document object
                                  Dim cimLayerDoc As CIMLayerDocument
                                  cimLayerDoc = lyrDoc.GetCIMLayerDocument

                                  ' Create a CIM Feature Layer object
                                  Dim cimFeaturelyr As CIMFeatureLayer
                                  cimFeaturelyr = CType(cimLayerDoc.LayerDefinitions(0), CIMFeatureLayer)

                                  ' Create a CIM Standard Data Connection
                                  Dim cimSDCon As CIMStandardDataConnection
                                  cimSDCon = CType(cimFeaturelyr.FeatureTable.DataConnection, CIMStandardDataConnection)

                                  ' Create a full path name string to feature class
                                  Dim sPath As String
                                  Dim sFC As String
                                  sPath = cimSDCon.WorkspaceConnectionString
                                  sFC = cimSDCon.Dataset
                                  Dim sFullpath As String
                                  sFullpath = sPath & "\" & sFC
                                  sFullpath = sFullpath.Remove(0, 9) ' Removes DATABASE= from start of string

                                  MsgBox(sFullpath, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Feature class Path")
                                  Return True
                              End Function)

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks tremendous, Idk what you exactly mean by *"almost 2 days"*, was it tough or easy?

Comment: I had to install VS 2022, that didn't work at first, couldn't get the templates to show up, that was literally a day of head banging, then the remarkable lack of VB sample code on the ESRI site hindered me as I'm a VB programmer not c#. Whilst I could understand the object model because its not dissimilar to ArcObjects,  I find the syntax of c# very cryptic and strangely hard to decipher.  I guess my brain is hard wired to VB! So 2 days... :)

Comment: Damn ... I can feel your dedication. It is impressive! I believe you slept with this task in your dreams :)